# Rocksdb concurrent Put performance

Tags: performance, put, rocksdb

I would like to show some experimental results about Rocksdb Put performance. The fact that single-threaded put throughput is slower than two-threaded put throughput. It is wired because it uses the default skiplist as memtable, and this data structure supports concurrent writes.

Here is my testing code.

```cpp
uint64_t nthread = 2;
  uint64_t nkeys = 16000000;
  std::thread threads[nthread];
  std::atomic<uint64_t> idx(1000000);

  for (int t = 0; t < nthread; t++) {
    threads[t] = std::thread([db, &idx, nthread, nkeys, &write_option_disable] {
      WriteBatch batch;
      for (int i = 0; i < nkeys / nthread; i++) {
        std::string key = "WVERIFY" + std::to_string(idx.fetch_add(1));
        std::string value = "MOCK";

        auto ikey = rocksdb::Slice(key);
        auto ivalue = rocksdb::Slice(value);
        db->Put(write_option_disable, ikey, ivalue);
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }
  for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
  }
```

Besides, here are the results I got.

```
// Single thread
Uptime(secs): 8.4 total, 8.3 interval
Flush(GB): cumulative 1.170, interval 1.170
AddFile(GB): cumulative 0.000, interval 0.000
AddFile(Total Files): cumulative 0, interval 0
AddFile(L0 Files): cumulative 0, interval 0
AddFile(Keys): cumulative 0, interval 0
Cumulative compaction: 1.17 GB write, 143.35 MB/s write, 0.00 GB read, 0.00 MB/s read, 8.1 seconds
Interval compaction: 1.17 GB write, 144.11 MB/s write, 0.00 GB read, 0.00 MB/s read, 8.1 seconds
Stalls(count): 0 level0_slowdown, 0 level0_slowdown_with_compaction, 0 level0_numfiles, 0 level0_numfiles_with_compaction, 0 stop for pending_compaction_bytes, 0 slowdown for pending_compaction_bytes, 0 memtable_compaction, 0 memtable_slowdown, interval 0 total count
Block cache LRUCache@0x564742515ea0#7011 capacity: 8.00 MB collections: 1 last_copies: 0 last_secs: 2e-05 secs_since: 8
Block cache entry stats(count,size,portion): Misc(1,0.00 KB,0%)

** File Read Latency Histogram By Level [default] **

** DB Stats **
Uptime(secs): 8.4 total, 8.3 interval
Cumulative writes: 16M writes, 16M keys, 16M commit groups, 1.0 writes per commit group, ingest: 1.63 GB, 199.80 MB/s
Cumulative WAL: 0 writes, 0 syncs, 0.00 writes per sync, written: 0.00 GB, 0.00 MB/s
Cumulative stall: 00:00:0.000 H:M:S, 0.0 percent
Interval writes: 16M writes, 16M keys, 16M commit groups, 1.0 writes per commit group, ingest: 1669.88 MB, 200.85 MB/s
Interval WAL: 0 writes, 0 syncs, 0.00 writes per sync, written: 0.00 GB, 0.00 MB/s
Interval stall: 00:00:0.000 H:M:S, 0.0 percent
```

```
// 2 threads
Uptime(secs): 31.4 total, 31.4 interval
Flush(GB): cumulative 0.183, interval 0.183
AddFile(GB): cumulative 0.000, interval 0.000
AddFile(Total Files): cumulative 0, interval 0
AddFile(L0 Files): cumulative 0, interval 0
AddFile(Keys): cumulative 0, interval 0
Cumulative compaction: 0.67 GB write, 21.84 MB/s write, 0.97 GB read, 31.68 MB/s read, 10.2 seconds
Interval compaction: 0.67 GB write, 21.87 MB/s write, 0.97 GB read, 31.72 MB/s read, 10.2 seconds
Stalls(count): 0 level0_slowdown, 0 level0_slowdown_with_compaction, 0 level0_numfiles, 0 level0_numfiles_with_compaction, 0 stop for pending_compaction_bytes, 0 slowdown for pending_compaction_bytes, 0 memtable_compaction, 0 memtable_slowdown, interval 0 total count
Block cache LRUCache@0x5619fb7bbea0#6183 capacity: 8.00 MB collections: 1 last_copies: 0 last_secs: 1.9e-05 secs_since: 31
Block cache entry stats(count,size,portion): Misc(1,0.00 KB,0%)

** File Read Latency Histogram By Level [default] **

** DB Stats **
Uptime(secs): 31.4 total, 31.4 interval
Cumulative writes: 16M writes, 16M keys, 11M commit groups, 1.4 writes per commit group, ingest: 0.45 GB, 14.67 MB/s
Cumulative WAL: 0 writes, 0 syncs, 0.00 writes per sync, written: 0.00 GB, 0.00 MB/s
Cumulative stall: 00:00:0.000 H:M:S, 0.0 percent
Interval writes: 16M writes, 16M keys, 11M commit groups, 1.4 writes per commit group, ingest: 460.94 MB, 14.69 MB/s
Interval WAL: 0 writes, 0 syncs, 0.00 writes per sync, written: 0.00 GB, 0.00 MB/s
Interval stall: 00:00:0.000 H:M:S, 0.0 percent
```

===========================update==========================

This is my Rocksdb's setting.

```cpp
DB* db;
  Options options;
  BlockBasedTableOptions table_options;
  rocksdb::WriteOptions write_option_disable;
  write_option_disable.disableWAL = true;
  // Optimize RocksDB. This is the easiest way to get RocksDB to perform well
  options.IncreaseParallelism();
  options.OptimizeLevelStyleCompaction();
  // create the DB if it's not already present
  options.create_if_missing = true;
```

Comment: did you enable concurrent writes on the memtable ?

Comment: @AsadAwadia Yes, the memtable enables concurrent writes by default now. I checked the test benchmark of leveldb. It uses the BatchWrite interface when it comes to concurrent writing. But in the read-whilewriting benchmark, it uses the Put interface to write data to leveldb because it is a single-threaded write.

Comment: post the proper code for both tests - there is a batch created but never used. Also keep the test loop to only have rocksdb - no nkeys / nthread type - just do a loop and write things out

Answer (score 0):

The atomic `idx` shared between two threads can introduced non-trivial overhead.  Try inserting random values from each thread, and maybe increase the number of threads.